# How to Check an Input Is Required in PHP

Tags: php

Is there any way to check if an input is required in PHP and HTML5 or not? I mean in case of validation we can simply ignore the inputs without "required" attribute but is there an any way to target all required ones?

```
Name: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
Age:  <input type="text" name="age">
```

some thing like

```
if (input === required){
  do validation
}
```

Comment: No. When a form is submitted, the server just gets the names and values, not any of the HTML attributes.

Comment: You need to decide which all fields are required

Comment: No. only the name=value data is submitted. Other attributes like "required" are not submitted with the form.

Comment: Can you check in the HTML5 page it self.

Comment: If a field is required it has been outputted using your server itself it means you already have records of which fields are mandatory

Comment: @Subhanker: not true. html5 constraints could be bypassed (I can submit whatever I want to an URL)

Comment: of course you can but here op wants to know if a field is required or not.

Comment: Hi everyone and thanks for reply but can you please let me know why some smart guys voting me down for this question?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with something like this

```
$required_fields = array('foo','bar','foobar');
foreach($required_fields as $required_field) {
  //check if field is setted
}
```

that way you can check for required fields.

Of course you have to write them down explicitly as form submit will submit only fields name and values, not attributes

Answer (score 1):

Server only receives name and values pairs (or something other particular data).
Note that Html attributes like "require" are only defined and accessible on client side (browser).